# How to send a file to the printer using command line options?

Tags: printing

I have a OKI printer which displays the job status while the file is processing, various methods have been used like **LPR** and **NET USE** for printing.All these methods are not replicating the file name and port name they just show the process status .

Could any one provide me with a solution to send a file to the printer so that i can have a look at the job list where can i know the status of the file which is being processed.

Comment: If your printer talks LPD, what is the output of LPQ? You're saying the filename is being lost at the printer's representation (happens, they might not care), or that your implementation of LPR is not passing filename along?

Comment: Not just a matter of thanks, it indicates the question was satisfactorily resolved.  You should accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to display the filename on the printer operator panel and in the printer's internal queue?  If so, you will most likely need to inject some PJL into your file.  Do a print to file from a Windows printer driver and see what it's injecting.  My guess is there is something like one of the following commands.

```
@PJL JOB NAME = "FILENAME"

or

@PJL RDYMSG DISPLAY = "FILENAME"
```

Ensure that you wrap this in the traditional PJL UEL.

If you are trying to insert some better info into the Windows spooler to avoid the traditional "Local Downlevel Document" then you will need to write you own app using something like this:

[How to send raw data to a printer by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091)

Here you could take the filename and pass it as pDocName.